# Resizing a view based on Appbar's offset or height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, contentoffset

I've been trying to imitate Trivago's very awesome Appbar~Cardview UI transition, but never had a luck for almost a week, I know its an appbar/collapsing/coordinator design, but I'm already exhausted trying, so I ended up with calculating the appbar's offset, adding it(its a negative so it will be subtracted) to a view's layout height,

```
// its a negative so if you add it, it will subtract
view.layoutParams.height = initialHeight + appbarOffset
```

It worked like a charm, until I fling it!.. sometimes the height of the view is not complete, the culprit is the appbar's offset, if you fling it, it will not continue to give you its minimum and maximum value... leaving the view's height dependent on it incomplete...  please have a look on my simple xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/appbar_layout_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coupons_lst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coupons_lst"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

heres how I do it on the kotlin side

```
   appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { 
            _, offset ->

        val positiveOffset = offset * -1

        if (positiveOffset > 10) {

            val layoutParams = cardView.layoutParams
            layoutParams.height = heightFromViewTreeObserver - positiveOffset
            cardView.layoutParams = layoutParams
        }
    })
```

[Initial Height of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZZWw.png)

[When scrolled up or down (slowly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHEEV.png)

[When fling or scrolled fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIiW8.png)

Its really hard for me to imitate trivago's way of making the height of a view dependent on the appbar's offset or height, If I put it inside the collapsing toolbar, its top part does not stop from its position, instead it goes up which is not what I desire...

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things it could be. 1. Whenever you uses ConstraintLayout you must implement the childrens views vertical and horizontal constraints. Failing to do so results in weird ui stuff. Example like so.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coupons_lst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="someId"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coupons_lst"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRigh_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Next I also noticed that you are not connecting the layouts with a parent layout. You have the opening Layout tag but I didn't see that in your posted code don't know if that was intentional or not.

Last but not least the Quirky UI issues I recently experienced were do to not setting my toolbar layout height to "?attr/actionBarSize". Try setting that on yours

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've been trying and tweaking many times, understanding how does trivago do it..

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#cececece"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cecece"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:background="#cececece">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolba3r"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cecece"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff00"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedShit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coupons_lst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coupons_lst"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Two appbarlayouts, its getting close to what I want to achieve, but the problem is that the appbarlayouts are flickering...